# How do you make a Directive reference to a Script without knowing the Script itself?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a nutshell, I have one script that has a bunch of functions and the bulk of my logic in it, and it needs a graph of nodes to operate. I have to do this for several difference graphs so I opted to have one logic script and make a new script for each of the graphs as I need to make them. This way I just have a variable in the logic script to reference whichever graph and that way I don't have to have the logic code paired with every single graph. The problem is that I don't know which graph I am referencing, and when you make a reference to a script in unity you have to do something like

```
public name_of_script graph;
```

Is there any way to remedy this or any variably type that acts as a var variable but for directive script references?

I tried monobehavior but if course that doesn't work, and I also tried var, which doesn't work either. It's not a problem with my code, when I use the name of a test script it works just fine.

Comment: does BroadcastMessage works for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you familiar with [generics in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)? You could define the class containing your shared functions like `public class SharedFunctions<TGraph> { /*... */ }` and instantiate it in your graph scripts like `var functions = new SharedFunctions<SomeGraph>()` where SomeGraph is the name of the class containing that particular graph script. Do all graph scripts implement a common interface? I've never used Unity, but with that information I might be able to post an answer rather than a comment

Comment: @sbridewell I am importing the script with the graph objects into the script that handles logic, I am not doing anything with the functions in the graph script. Also you can't use generics because every Unity script extends an abstract class.